# How do I use @layer in CSS in VSCode?

Tags: html, css, css-layer

The @layer CSS at-rule declares a cascade layer. Rules within a cascade layer cascade together, giving more control over the cascade to web developers.

```
@layer utilities {
  .padding-sm {
    padding: .5rem;
  }

  .padding-lg {
    padding: .8rem;
  }
}
```

I can use @layer in Codepen and it works fine. But I do I get it to work on VSCode?

Comment: It's experimental feature that is not supported by any browser, so no wonder other tools does not support it too.

Comment: @Justinas I understand that but there are browsers like Chrome Canary that do. I'm trying to figure out how I can try out this feature while wanting to coding in VSCode instead of Codepen.

Comment: Write plugin for VSCode

Comment: @Justinas It was already supported by Firefox 97 released the day before your comment (February 8). It is also now supported in Chrome 99 released yesterday (March 1).